# How can I access the id parameter in a @Secured() expression when the id is pulled from the url

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a controller that uses @Secured() to restrict access to an action based on the specific domain object being processed:

```
@Secured('@permissionChecker.isLocationAdmin()')
public edit(Location location) {
  // [code]
}
```

Based on [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297006/grails-spring-security-expression-how-to-access-method-parameter), I know I can't pass the location object to the permission checker.  When using the proposed workaround (in the permissionChecker.isLocationAdmin code),

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
...
def params = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.params
```

I can get access to the id parameter **if** I use the url `https://.../edit?id=42`.

However, if I use `https://.../edit/42`, params object is empty.  When I look at the params in the controller, `controller`, `action`, and `id` are set.  The params object I get in the controller is also not the same (according to the debugger).

My UrlMappings are pretty straight forward, with the relevant entry:

```
"/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
  constraints {
    // apply constraints here
  }
}
```

What seems to work so far is pulling the id out of the url by hand:

```
def params = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.params
String idStr = params.id
if (!idStr) {
  String url = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes).request.getRequestURI()
  int idx = url.lastIndexOf('/')
  if (url &&  idx >= 0) {
    idStr = url.substring(idx + 1)
  }
}
```

but this seems wrong and fragile.  Is there a better way?

Comment: have you tried params without any declaration of it ? i mean String idStr = params.id and take off def params. A good test is to do println "$params" at the top of any controller you wish to inspect to see what params are coming in

Comment: The code in question is in the permission checker (question details edited to clarify).  If I do not pull the params from the RequestContextHolder, it's just not defined (Message: No such property: params for class: ...)

Comment: sorry I realised after posting the same issue with cross reference to other post. You could try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html url and parsing path but unsure if anything is gained tbh